Using the definition, describe the backward error analysis and error bound of the eigen value problem.
By the definition 6.2.4.2, I tried to understand the cocept of backward error analysis of the Backward Error anlaysis for Eigenvalue problem,
$f: \mathscr D\subset \mathbb C^{n,n}\to \mathbb C.$
$$f(A):=\text{Eigenvalue of } A$$
$\tilde{f}:\mathscr D\subset \mathbb C^{n,n}\to \mathbb C$ be the computer implication.
The computer implication is backward stable there exists some $\tilde{A}\in \mathscr D\subset \mathbb C^{n,n}: \exists \delta>0 ,||A-\tilde A||<\delta \implies \tilde f(A)=f(\tilde A).$
Could you tell me whether my understanding is correct or not? $\delta$ is the backward error bound. Right?

No. Your use of the implication arrow is incorrect.
Let $f : \mathbb{C}^{m \times m} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$ denote a function such that $\lambda = f(A) \in \mathbb{C}^m$ is a vector that consists of the eigenvalues of $A$. A computer implementation $A \rightarrow g(A)$ for evaluating $A \rightarrow f(A)$ is said to be normwise relative backwards stable if and only if
$$ \forall A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m} \: \exists C > 0 \: \exists \Delta A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m} \: : \: \Big[ g(A) = f(A + \Delta A) \wedge \|\Delta A\| \leq C \|A\| u \Big]$$
where $u$ is the unit roundoff and good software has small values of $C$.
In short, the computed eigenvalues $\hat{\lambda}$ must be the exact eigenvalues of a matrix $A+\Delta A$ that is close to the original matrix $A$ in the sense that $$ \|\Delta A\| \leq C\|A\| u.$$
This is an extremely powerful condition because we can reduce the right hand-side as much as we like by migrating our software to a more expensive computer with a smaller value of $u$ or by using a library for doing arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Thank you for the wonderful answer. I will read carefully. I will ask doubt, If I have any.

@Unknownx You are very welcome. I have corrected a sentence that was garbled.

@Unknownx Has the question been resolved?

Yes @Carlchristian
